# How to pattern match exist to transform proofs

Tags: recursion, pattern-matching, coq, coq-tactic

I'm messing around with coq and I'm trying to create a function that can be used to lookup something in a list and return an associated proof with it that the specified element is in the list.

In my case I have a list of tuples and I want to lookup based on the first element of the tuple.

So first I defined an `assoc` inductive predicate that proves an element is in the list. This has two cases. Either the element is in the head of the list or it is in the tail.

```
Inductive assoc (A : Set) (B : Set) : list (A * B) -> A -> B -> Prop :=
  | assocHead : forall (l : list (A * B)) (a : A) (b : B), assoc A B (cons (a,b) l) a b
  | assocTail : forall (l : list (A * B)) (a x : A) (b y : B), assoc A B l a b -> assoc A B ((x,y) :: l) a b.
```

Then I define a `lookup` function that given a list of tuples, a first element and an equality predicate returns either None or Some with the looked up element and a proof that the element is in the list.

```
Program Fixpoint lookup
  (A : Set)
  (B : Set)
  (dec : (forall x y : A, {x = y} + {x <> y}))
  (l : list (A * B))
  (a : A)
  {struct l}
  : option {b : B | assoc A B l a b}
:= match l with
   | [] => None
   | (pair v t) :: tl => if dec v a
                           then (Some (exist (assoc A B ((pair v t) :: tl) a) t (assocHead A B tl a t)))
                           else match (lookup A B dec tl a) with
                           -- In the case below we have proven it's in the
                           -- tail of the list.
                           -- How to use that to create new proof with assocTail?
                           | Some (exist _ _ _) => None
                           | None => None
                           end
   end.
```

The way it's written above compiles fine. But I can't figure out how to use the proof that is in the `tl` of the list to create a new proof that it's in the total list. I have tried various things like pattern matching in the third argument of `exist` but I can never get it to work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it's probably better to write `assoc` like this

```
Inductive assoc {A B : Type} (k : A) (v : B) : list (A * B) -> Prop :=
| assoc_head : forall l, assoc k v ((k, v) :: l)
| assoc_tail : forall l x, assoc k v l -> assoc k v (x :: l).
Arguments assoc_head {A B} {k v}, {A B} k v, A B k v.
Arguments assoc_tail {A B} {k v} {l}, {A B} {k v} l, {A B} k v l, A B k v l.
```

Basically, the more things you can fit on the left side of the `:`, the easier it is to deal with the type (more parameters, fewer indices). I'd actually go further and write

```
Inductive elem {A : Type} (x : A) : list A -> Prop :=
| in_here : forall l, elem x (x :: l)
| in_there : forall l y, elem x l -> elem x (y :: l).
Definition assoc {A B : Type} (k : A) (v : B) l := elem (k, v) l.
```

but that's getting sidetracked.

Anyway, you don't need to inspect the third argument of `exists` in your code. You just give it to `assoc_tail`. Done.

```
#[program] Fixpoint lookup
  {A B : Type} (dec : forall x y : A, {x = y} + {x <> y})
  (l : list (A * B)) (k : A) {struct l}
: option {v : B | assoc k v l}
:=
  match l with
  | [] => None
  | (k', v') as h :: l =>
    if dec k' k (* writing the first argument to exist is usually just clutter *)
      then Some (exist _ v' (assoc_head k' v' l))
      else
        match lookup dec l k with
        | Some (exist _ v prf) => Some (exist _ v (assoc_tail h prf))
        | None => None
        end
  end.
```

Do note that part of the magic of `Program` is that it's supposed to let you write the actual *program* without worrying about the proof part first. In particular, you're supposed to imagine that values with refined type like `x : {v : B | assoc k v l}` are just `x : B`, and then the proof part of the refinement is handled later.

```
#[program] Fixpoint lookup
  {A B : Type} (dec : forall x y : A, {x = y} + {x <> y})
  (l : list (A * B)) (k : A) {struct l}
: option {v : B | assoc k v l}
:=
  match l with
  | [] => None
  | (k', v') :: l =>
    if dec k' k
      then Some v'
      else
        match lookup dec l k with (* looks weird but is still necessary *)
        | Some v => Some v
        | None => None
        end
  end.
Solve Obligations with program_simpl; now constructor.
```

On that note, `lookup` can do better than just return an `option`!

```
#[local] Hint Constructors assoc : core.
#[local] Unset Program Cases.

#[program] Fixpoint lookup
  {A B : Type} (dec : forall x y : A, {x = y} + {x <> y})
  (l : list (A * B)) (k : A) {struct l}
: {v : B | assoc k v l} + {~exists v : B, assoc k v l}
:=
  match l with
  | [] => inright _ (* Underscores as an "escape hatch" to an obligation *)
  | (k', v') :: l =>
    if dec k' k
      then inleft v'
      else
        match lookup dec l k with
        | inleft v => inleft v
        | inright no => inright _
        end
  end.
Next Obligation.
  intros [v no].
  inversion no.
Qed.
Next Obligation.
  intros [v nono].
  inversion nono as [? | ? ? nono']; eauto.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

After pattern-matching on the pair `exist` from the recursive call, you know the first component of the pair is also the first component of your result. Then the second component is a proof that you can fill up as a separate obligation.

```
match lookup ... with
| Some (exist _ b _) => Some (exist _ b _ (* this underscore becomes an obligation *))
| None => None
end
```

That allows the `Program Definition` command to complete, and then you have to prove an obligation (a lemma) to actually finish that definition. Be sure to terminate the proof with `Defined` instead of `Qed` because the guardedness checker somehow needs your proof to be transparent.

```
Next Obligation.
  (* finish the proof *)
Defined.
```

---

```
Program Fixpoint lookup
  (A : Set)
  (B : Set)
  (dec : (forall x y : A, {x = y} + {x <> y}))
  (l : list (A * B))
  (a : A)
  {struct l}
  : option {b : B | assoc A B l a b}
:= match l with
   | [] => None
   | (pair v t) :: tl =>
     if dec v a
     then (Some (exist (assoc A B ((pair v t) :: tl) a) t (assocHead A B tl a t)))
     else match (lookup A B dec tl a) with
          | Some (exist _ b _) => Some (exist _ b _)
          | None => None
          end
   end.

Next Obligation.
  apply assocTail.
  assumption.
Defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a predicate `In` in the library that specifies whether a list contains an element, so you don't really need to define a new `assoc` predicate.

And you could try to use the `refine` tactic which I find really helpful to build up the term step by step. It is a bit like using `Program` but it feels less magical. You write as much of the term as you can (i.e. the match statement that a `destruct` would generate), and put in `_` where you want to get a proof obligation. You can use proof tactics for the obligations, and see what kind of term you build up.  It can be quite enlightening.

I ended up with this program:

```
Require Import List.

Fixpoint lookup {A B} (dec: forall (a a':A), {a=a'}+{a<>a'})
         (l:list (A*B)) (a:A) {struct l} : option {b | In (a,b) l}.
  refine (
      match l with
      | nil => None
      | cons (a',b) l' =>
        match dec a a' with
        | left _ y => Some (exist _ b (or_introl _))
        | right _ y  =>
          match lookup _ _ dec l' a with
          | None => None
          | Some (exist _ b' H') => Some (exist _ b' (or_intror H'))
          end
        end
      end).
  congruence.
Defined.
```

Note that I for pedagogical reasons left one `_` in the term, that was taken care of with the `congruence` tactic.